# How to add an increment value for each id attribute within the div contents with cloned jQuery object

Tags: clone, jquery, jquery-click-event

Having a hard time figuring out how to add an increment value for each id attribute within the div contents with cloned jQuery object.

http://jsfiddle.net/hvK8d/

===================== HTML=====================

```
    <div class="upload-file-container">
  <div class="uploadFile left clearfix">
    <input type="file" id="FileUpload1">
    <table id="RadioButtonList1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="radio" value="Resume"  id="RadioButtonList1_1">
            <label for="RadioButtonList1_1">Resume</label></td>
          <td><input type="radio" value="Letter of Recommendation"  id="RadioButtonList1_2">
            <label for="RadioButtonList1_2">Letter of Recommendation</label></td>
          <td><input type="radio" value="Other"  id="RadioButtonList1_3">
            <label for="RadioButtonList1_3">Other</label></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="remove left">Remove</a> </div>
<div class=""><a class="plus" href="javascript:;">plus one</a></div>
```

===================== JQUERY =====================

```
    //Cloning upload file control
$('.remove').live('click', function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this item?")) {
        $(this).parent().slideUp('fast', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$('.plus').click(function () {
    console.log('cloning');
    var divCloned = $('.upload-file-container:first').clone();
    divCloned.hide().insertAfter('.upload-file-container:last').slideDown('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that much code - why not post it in here and give the fiddle link as a reference.  What if jsfiddle gets closed down?  We wouldn't be able to help you :)

Comment: It is not clear to me what question you are asking.

Comment: For me it is not clear why you want that - notice you don't even have `name` attributes in your example. Is it incomplete?

Comment: every time the '.upload-file-container' gets clones, the IDs needs to be different then the first '.upload-file-container'

Comment: If you can please explain to us what the desired effect is and exactly  what the problem is - It'll make it much easier to give you advice...

Comment: I'm only worried about the IDs

Comment: @user952851, `name`s are important

Comment: @user952851, I posted a simple templating solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I will put here a small solution making use of a "template."

A class for hiding the template:

```
.upload-file-container.template {
  display: none;
}  ​
```

A small function to do replacements:

```
$.fn.template = function(variables) {
  return this.each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/{{(.+)}}/g, function(match, variable) {
      return variables[variable];
    });
    return this;
  });
};
```

A template:

```
<div class="upload-file-container template">
  <div class="uploadFile left clearfix">
    <input type="file" id="FileUpload{{id}}">
    <table id="RadioButtonList{{id}}"><tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="Resume"  id="RadioButtonList{{id}}_1">
          <label for="RadioButtonList{{id}}_1">Resume</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
var count = 0;

var divCloned = $(".upload-file-container.template")
  .clone()
  .removeClass("template")
  .template({
    id: count++
  });
```

Comment: @user952851, I just changed the order of the `removeClass` statement

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using numbered IDs, you should be using the array-like notation (e.g. `RadioButtonList[]`) in the `name` attribute, and wrap your labels around the `input`s:

```
<td>
    <label for="RadioButtonList1_1">
        <input type="radio" value="Resume" name="RadioButtonList1[]">
        Resume
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label for="RadioButtonList1_2">
        <input type="radio" value="Letter of Recommendation" name="RadioButtonList2[]">
        Letter of Recommendation
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label for="RadioButtonList1_3">
        <input type="radio" value="Other" name="RadioButtonList3[]">
        Other
    </label>
</td>
```

**P.S.** You should also consider using a more descriptive name than *RadioButtonList*.