# Add/remove divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I changed my code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#add').on('click', function () {
                var $contacts = $(".contact");
                $("<div/>").append($("<input>", {
                  "type": "text",
                  "name": "contact[" + $contacts.length + "][name]"
                })).insertAfter($contacts.last());
            });
          });   

<div class="contact">
Name: &nbsp; <input type="contact[0][name] type="text">
</div>
<div class="contact">
Name: &nbsp; <input type="contact[1][name] type="text">
</div>
<div class="contact">
Name: &nbsp; <input type="contact[2][name] type="text">
</div>
```

This works and allows me to add another row. However, I need help on two things:

1) When I add another row and hit submit. The $_POST array only shows the first three values, not the dynamically added arrays.

2) How do I add more the text to the appended html? It only shows the input box, not "Name: " in front of it.

Thanks!

This is what print_r($_POST) is returning (I have other form fields in there):

```
 Post:
 Array
  (
[custsubmit] => Submit
[contact] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [name] => name1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [name] => name2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [name] => name3
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: first of all this is very bad practice to give same id to different elements..you can use class instead of id ,if you want to select multiple elements at one shot

Comment: This is similar to this question.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426238/add-i-for-each-new-row-that-will-created-by-the-button

Comment: Why you tagged mysql and PHP?

Comment: Ok. I'm working on it now and I will post my updates soon. I'm going to change everything to class and not id. I've been doing this erroneously and will need to go change all of my code eventually.

Comment: See the updates above. I changed my original post. I'm not sure if that is how this site is supposed to work as I'm now. Is it ok to change the original text or how should I post added/altered code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using a multidimensional array.

```
<div class="contact">
  <input type="text" name="contact[0][name]">
  ...
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <input type="text" name="contact[1][name]">
  ...
</div>
...
```

I changed the `id` of your `<div>` container to a classname since the `id` attribute is meant to be unique.

Now, to add a new row you can use something as follows.

```
var $contacts = $(".contact");
$("<div/>", {
  "class": "contact",
  "html": $("<input>", {
    "type": "text",
      "name": "contact[" + $contacts.length + "][name]"
  })
}).insertAfter($contacts.last());
```

This way, you will receive a nice array in PHP to work with which will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => foo
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bar
        )
    ...
)
```

---

You can use more complicated layout by making use of a DOM template as [I previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617734/417685).

```
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

```
<div class="contact template">Name: &nbsp;
  <input type="contact[{{id}}][name]" type="text">
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  var $template = $(".template");
  $('#add').on('click', function () {
    var $contacts = $(".contact").not(".template");
    $template.template({
      id: $contacts.length
    }).insertAfter($contacts.last());
  });
});
```

[You can see it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8x5p5/)

Comment: I got it work; however, it's not adding the value to "$_POST". I currently have three rows and when I "add" another row and submit it only shows the three existing rows in the "contact" Array.

Comment: @XanderNGCC, can you show what is the new face of your code? What is `print_r($_POST)` returning now?

Comment: @XanderNGCC, I updated the answer to add the `contact` class which was missing. But, my guess is that the new elements may be appended outside of the `<form>`? Can you give more context on this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking they are outside the <form> as well, but I can't figure it out. </form> is the next tag after my "contact" class divs so I'm not sure why it's not catching it. Is it possible to view the "active" source code after i press "add" to see where this code is being inserted?

Comment: Also, is it possible add more text to the "added" code? I'd like to add "Name: " in front of the added input form. It will eventually be a block of inputs added each type the "add" button is pressed.

Comment: @XanderNGCC, yes, you can. But, it depends of your browser. For example, use the Developer Tools in Chrome, Firebug plug-in for Firefox or built-in DOM inspector of Firefox. For adding a more complicated layout it's better if you use a [DOM template as I have explained in this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11617734/417685)

Comment: I figured out the <form> issue. I had to move it outside of a div to get it to worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will look into the DOM template and see if that helps.
How do I mark this question "answered" and/or award you any points for helping? I'm new here.
Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, thanks. A quick question on the template stuff: I'm looking at the four parts. 1) I need to define a template somewhere in the html. 2) Add a <script> with the class for hiding. 2) Add the small replacements functions in the <script> as well. 4) Using the $('#add').on('click', function () I can call the "usage" code to actually trigger the event?

Comment: Cool! Thanks! That site is awesome. I've never used it before.

Comment: how would I modify my code to be able to remove a div? I got the addition to work fine, but I'd like to be able to remove one if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To do it "properly" you need some sort of MVC (model-view-controller) or similar design. You should look into some client side framework (such as Angular.js, Backbone, etc..) that makes life easier.

If you want to do without a framework - one (relatively) simple way would be to keep a template as a string (see example below).
Then keep a counter in javascript, increment it as you add a row, replace the template variable(s) and use the resulting string as innerHtml, ie:

```
var contactTemplate = '<input type="text" name="contact{{id}}" id="contact{{id}}" val="{{Name}}">...';
var counter = 1;
var addContact = function(data) {
    counter++;
    var html = contactTemplate.replace(/{{id}}/g, counter).replace(/{{Name}}/g, data.Name);
    var newElement = $('<div>'+html+'</div>');
    $('#container').append(newelement);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#add').on('click', function () {
      var newID = 'contact' + ($('input:text').length + 1 );
      newDiv = '<input type="text" name="' + newID + '" id="' + newID + '" value="' + newID + '" />';
      $('#contact').html( $('#contact').html() + newDiv );
  });
});
```

Where, the HTML is like this:

```
<input type='button' id="add" value="Add more" />
<br />
<div id="contact">
  <input type="text" name="contact1" id="contact1" />
  <input type="text" name="contact2" id="contact2" />
  <input type="text" name="contact3" id="contact3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a single div around your inputs, then you can use [jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append) to put another input at the end of the list.   Also each time you create an element you can get the number of inputs in the single div by calling `.children().length` take that number add 1.